# After Image drag and drop make AJAX save to save image and its class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where i am dragging image from one div and dropping it into another div. After drop event user has to click the save button for saving the data in database by making a get request .But after the button is clicked page is refreshed and that image is again in the previous div.

so what i can do to make a AJAX call so that image and its class is saved after drop event ?

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    adFitsApp.set_app_cookie("{{ adftoken }}", "{{ adfdy }}");
    $('#sortable1 img').css("cursor", "pointer");


    $( "#sortable1 div" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "div",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {

            if($('#sortable2').find('img').length==6) {
                $('#btn-start').html("<a id='btn-start' href='/dashboard/redeem/{{ pk }}' >Redeem Coupon</a>");
            }
        }
    });

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "div",
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
            ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
        }
    });
    $('#sortable2').find('img').length
});
```

Comment: after every drop event save the images to db by ajax and then load the  second div with saved images in db

Comment: Or you may use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

> Sorry but I have no knowledge of ajax can you please give a demo how I
>   can do that

[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is basically just a way to send requests in JS (JQuery)

Using it is really simple:

```
$("element").on("event", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "your_url",
        data: {your: "data"},
        success: function(data) { 
            //success
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //error
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Code**

For you, I'd try this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/save" data-pk="{{ pk }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed">Save</a>
</div>

$("#btn-start").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: {pk: $(this).data("pk")},
        success: function(data) {
            //success here
        },
        error: function(data) {
           //error here
        }
    });
});
```